# How do I variate the color along one axis?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

So I have a laser-exhaust on my spaceship, coming out of the engines.
[image]

David already helped me variate the strength of the beam along the length, so it can taper off or remain strong along the length of the mesh.

But I also need to variate the color along the axis.

I'm modeling it after this: http://web.ccpgamescdn.com/newssystem/media/63965/1/EVE_Online_Retribution_OREFrigate.jpg

Which to be honest, I'm wondering if I need to scrap this material and try something else, but this feels above my head, I need some help.

Comment: use the color ramp the same way as fading but instead (yellow->orange )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a second color ramp node with the desired colors and plug it into the emission shader:

[image]